# PHP displays differently through firewall

Tags: php, html, firewall

I am playing around on my personal website with some PHP and MySQL.  At home, everything displays fine.  At work, however, if the PHP code is using GD to manipulate images nothing ever shows up on the page.  If it is just displaying HTML, it shows the HTML tags along with the text without ever formatting it.  It takes a very long time to finish being busy even if it has displayed all the information already.

This obviously seems to me to be a security setting on my work firewall, but I know of PHP sites that I can access which do not have that issue.  Is there a setting in PHP which I have not set up which might be causing this?  Does this sound familair to anyone?

One of the example bits of code I was using was

```
<?php

echo '<HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>';

//For loop to loop through this 100 times
for ($x = 1; $x <= 100; $x++) {
//Generate three random R, G, and B integers for an RGB value using mt_rand()
$r = mt_rand(0, 255);
$g = mt_rand(0, 255);
$b = mt_rand(0, 255);

//Turn them into a hex code:
$hexCode = dechex( (($r & 0xFF) << 16) | (($g & 0xFF) << 8) | ($b & 0xFF));
echo 'RED: ' . $r . ' GRN: ' . $g . ' BLU: ' . $b . '<BR>Hex Code: '. $hexCode . '<BR><BR>';
// End Bracket for the For loop
}
echo '</BODY></HTML>';
?>
```

As you can see, nothing too fancy.

I have tried to open this page in Firefox, Chrome, and IE, it only 'fails' at work.  In this case, it fails by displaying some number (which isn't echoed in the code at all), and then the page with HTML visible not treated as a markup.

[snippet of HTML output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c31Pi.gif)

Anybody know some way to get my simple test pages displaying on my work computer?

I am using personal development time to refresh my memory on some PHP concepts and MySQL concepts in preparation for an upcoming project.  I wanted to use my personal server to run these test programs rather than cluttering the work linux box I share with my partner up with my personal workspace.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does the complete browser page source look like when it's incorrectly rendered?

Comment: I notice it is missing a closing single quote after `</HTML>` and that makes me wonder if you are seeing partial error output.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski right clicking and View Page Source in firefox displays the same result, just without word wrapping.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski tthank you for pointing out that missed closing single quote, it is not in the source file on the server however (I wrote up this copy by hand, it was a re-typing typo.)

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Certainly for the gd issue it will probably be that the gd extension is not present. In any case, you always should do this when developing and testing code. At the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: If it's not rendering the HTML, check your browser's console to see what headers were sent. By default, PHP should send a `Content-Type: text/html` header without needing to do anything. But some misconfiguration could be preventing that, and the browser then interprets it as text/plain or something else.

Comment: Are you sure GD is installed? By default it is not installed nor configured.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the GD extension is present, and all code using it functions while accessing the page from home.  Test code above also functions while at home.  All my errors are output into an errors.txt file in the same folder as the script in which the error occurred with a log of any various failures.  There are no errors being logged, the scripts execute just fine apparently as well as they do when accessed from my home computer...they are just not being displayed properly on my work computer.  I am accessing the same URL in both cases.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski When examining the browser console it tells me "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."  added meta tag to declare encoding to be utf-8, browser console message is gone but file still displays with HTML markups visible.

Comment: Are you in control of the php install on your work computer? The `4000` output before the HTML tag is suspicious, and only really possible if there's some [`auto_prepend_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) occurring, where some other code is included/executed before yours is processed. If you just create a simple `<?php echo '<strong>hello world</strong>'; ?>` you may get similarly broken output.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski its not installed on my work computer, its running on a web server I pay hosting for. 

I have not configured the php installation on the server at all, using it 'out of the box' as it was installed by the host service.

PHP is currently 5.3, I access it through CPanel, there is no auto_prepend_file option on the options page where I can select the version, extensions, and option flags.

Comment: Sorry, I finally understand -  PHP runs in the same place but displays differently where viewed. That's very unusual and very suspicious. Watch the Network tab of the browser console while loading the page. Do any other files get sent along, like extra JavaScript from the hosting company? And I think I asked already  - when viewed at work is the HTML source exactly the same as expected? Does it make a difference if you add a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of the document?  I really have no idea what the firewall is doing, as I've never encountered one that active interferes with web content

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski This was very helpful.

I set up a self-signed SSL for this domain.  I had been able to access pages on the site before without having an SSL, looks like perhaps some other security measures were set since then.

Very frustrating in that it would not inform me the page wasn't loading because the site wasn't 'secure' until I opened the developer network window.  It loaded, just incompletely, and never blipped about not having an SSL.  >.<

Comment: @CharlynPemberton Glad you got it sorted out. You should probably post your findings as an answer below so you can return after the waiting period and mark it as completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the site when attempting to load the page had no SSL Certificate.  I had previously not needed one, but some settings had obviously been adjusted at my work's network security.

However, since I was accessing the site the way I had previously, through `HTTP://sitenamehere.etc/pagename.php`, no browser displayed an error that it wasn't loading specifically because there was no SSL...it was simply processing the output while displying the HTML as plain text and without displaying any of the images.

Using the browser's developer tools to view the network tab, I could see that the site was being flagged as not being secure.  Generating a self-signed SSL and accessing the page from `HTTPS://sitenamehere.etc/pagename.php` finally displayed the 'This site is not safe!' dialog page and allowed me to add an exception.

Thanks to [Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski) for walking me through these troubleshooting steps that led to this solution.  Hopefully this helps other people out there learning PHP while accessing it remotely.